# How to Change reCAPTCHA Enterprise Threshold for Firebase App Check?

Tags: firebase-security, firebase-app-check, recaptcha-enterprise

I'm working with Firebase App Check and I’m using ReCaptcha Enterprise to protect my Firebase app and functions.
In the google cloud console /  ReCaptcha Enterprise metrics section for my key, I see options for "Threshold recommendation" with values like Balanced, Low, and High. It appears that my current setting is Balanced, which results in requests with an assessment score lower than 0.6 returning a 401 error when calling my Firebase function protected with `enforceAppCheck: true`.

[image: ReCAPTCHA enterprise threshold recommendations]

I'd like to adjust the threshold setting for my reCAPTCHA key to better suit my application's needs. As shown in the image above, the threshold recommendations are provided, and I can simulate the threshold and estimate the score threshold effect. However, I can't seem to actually change the threshold here.

Could someone guide me on how to change the reCAPTCHA key threshold used by App Check?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct way to edit it out, but you could try editing it via google cloud CLI.

You can try to run this command.

```
gcloud recaptcha enterprise key update <PROJECT_ID> <KEY_ID> --challenge_security_level=<THRESHOLD_VALUE>
```

- where Project ID is your Project ID.
- Key ID is your reCAPTCHA key ID.
- THRESHOLD_VALUE is your desired value (e.g., 0.4).

Based on this [document](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key-website#create-key)

> "Note: After creating reCAPTCHA keys, you can edit or delete them. You
> cannot recover deleted keys."

You also need to enable your reCAPTCHA [Enterprise API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api) for your project. Once enabled you can try to use curl or any programming language library that can interact with the reCAPTCHA Enterprise API's "keys.update" You can further check it [here](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs).

For your server-side code, you can further look into Firebase's Admin SDK for managing reCAPTCHA settings, more info [here](https://firebase.google.com/s/results/?q=recaptcha%20enterprise)

Although there is no official documentation that I've come across, be wary of the limitation of its functionality.

Based on my understanding you're using a reCaptcha Enterprise, you can reach for [support](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/support) for proper alternative or resolution for your desired outcome.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately, it doesn't resolve my issue.
The command `gcloud recaptcha enterprise keys update` does not exist in my Google Cloud Shell. The `--challenge_security_level` option is also unavailable.
However, I do have `gcloud recaptcha keys` commands. There is a command to change the security preference level, but it is not applicable for my key:
`gcloud recaptcha keys update <PROJECT_ID> <KEY_ID> --preference=usability --web`
ERROR: (gcloud.recaptcha.keys.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Challenge security preference cannot be set for the SCORE option.